# UISplitViewController's detail view push error

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm implementing a universal app using `UISplitViewController` for iOS8 and facing strange problem with the `UINavigation` and would really appreciate your expertise.

My project has the following StoryBoard layout: [image: UINavigation in UISplitViewController]

On iPad, everything is working as expected. However, running on the iPhone, the navigation doesn't work as expected. Please see this [short video](https://youtu.be/_bZMXD0nouQ) demonstrating the navigation problem as I navigate from "Detail Screen 2" back to "Detail Screen 1".

I tried implementing this same scenario on a brand new project but I did not see the problem. Only after porting into my existing project do I see this behavior.

**UPDATE 1**:

Here is my AppDelegate code:

```
    @interface AppDelegate () <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

    @end

    @implementation AppDelegate

    -(BOOL) application: (UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*) launchOptions {

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        splitViewController.delegate = self;

        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;

        return YES;
    }

    #pragma mark - Split view

    - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {

        return YES;
    }

....
@end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to PetahChristian, I think his observation below is correct:

> To collapse a secondary view controller which has a navigation
>   controller, Apple inserts the secondary navigation controller onto the
>   primary navigation controller's stack. So, for the iPhone, where you
>   see the problems, it looks like there is only one navigation
>   controller, but there actually are two.

Assuming that observation is correct, how can the secondary navigation controller be prevented from pushing onto the primary navigation controller? The `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` methods only handle collapse logic for secondary view controller DIRECTLY linked to the `UISplitViewController`. In my case, the secondary view controller to be collapsed (namely **Detail VC1**) is routed via "*Show Detail (e.g. Replace)*" segue from the master view controller and the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` methods doesn't execute during this transition.

With the exact same setup on a brand new project, Apple doesn't insert the secondary navigation controller onto the primary navigation controller and I don't experience this problem on a new project.

Many thanks.

Comment: I read your updated question.  The secondary view controller really is the secondary navigation controller.  Look at your storyboard.  You can see the secondary navigation controller, with Detail VC1 as its child.  When the splitView collapses, the secondary navigation controller has to collapse on the primary.  Apple really does insert the secondary navigation controller into the primary view controller.  That's why they test for `[secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]...`  See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you PetahChristain. I absolutely appreciate your help on this topic, you helped me understand more about UISplitViewControllerDelegate.  I found the culprit to my problem and posted my answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit causing this navigation peculiarity in my project was due to an extension I downloaded from SO user called `UIViewController+BackButtonHandler`.  This handler intercept the navigation back button so I can get the chances to do extra work when user press back.  This category extension code overrides `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:` causing the default navigation to break.  I had no idea this code was executing because I wasn't utilizing it but rather, just incorporating in my project. Wow... 2 days of banging my head against the wall.

Comment: I'm very happy you found the problem!  A good rule of thumb is that if we have to "work around" Apple's way of doing things, we are likely missing the proper way to handle it.  If you ask SO how to do extra work when the user presses back, you may find a better way to accomplish it that doesn't involve intercepting normal behavior :)

Comment: @Loc Pham you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

It behaves differently between projects because the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` code is different.

The new project has the necessary code, but the existing project may be missing it.

Check your AppDelegate and compare the code that handles collapsing and separating the secondary view controller.

```
-splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:
-splitViewController:separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:
```

**Update:**

You shouldn't unconditionally return YES in `splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:`.  You need to first determine which view controller is on the top:  See how they check to see if it is the (secondary navigation controller, and its child) detail view controller, and it has details to show?

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]] && ([(DetailViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] detailItem] == nil)) {
        // Return YES to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

To collapse a secondary view controller which has a navigation controller, Apple inserts the secondary navigation controller onto the primary navigation controller's stack. So, for the iPhone, where you see the problems, it looks like there is only one navigation controller, but there actually are two.

In your video, when it looks like you are at the master, but it has a back button, and you tap it, and the back button slides off the screen, that's the secondary navigation controller disappearing from the primary navigation controller.

For your project to properly work, you'll have to conditionally test for the navigation controller, like apple does, to determine whether the (navigation controller and its child) detail view controller get discarded or not.

**Update 3:**

A navigation controller, in itself, is a view controller.  It controls its children view controllers.

The secondary navigation controller *is* the secondary view controller.  The detail view controller is its child view controller.

What the splitView delegate methods are handling are the collapse or separation of the secondary navigation controller, which happens to have one or more child view controllers.

When the splitView controller is collapsed, the primary navigation controller's stack looks like [masterViewController, secondaryNavigationController].

As for the replace segue, what you are replacing is the Empty detail view controller in the bottom of the Storyboard, with the orange Detail Screen 1.  But the replaced detail view controller still has a parent, the secondary navigation controller.  And when the splitViewController collapses, the secondary navigation controller ends up on the primary navigation controller stack.  You don't see this, because it's transparent.  All you see is the Detail screen 1 because it's the top view controller of the secondary navigation controller.

Your splitViewDelegate code is broken.  This is why the view controllers don't animate properly in the video when you tap the Back button.  Fix the delegate code, and all **will** look and work correctly.

You definitely need both the collapse and the separate methods, and they need to do the right thing.  That's why I'm recommending you use Apple's code, instead of trying to write your own, because Apple's code correctly collapses and separates the navigation controller.

Comment: My UISplitViewControllerDelegate method is dead-on simple, it simply returns YES for splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController: and I'm not implementing the -splitViewController:separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:

Comment: Post your `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` code.  There is a bug in it, because the existing project is not properly handling the primary and secondary view controllers.  That's what's affecting the views from popping off the navigation controller stack properly.

Comment: I modified my question to include the AppDelegate code. Thanks.

Comment: You have to implement both methods properly, or it will make the wrong determination on when to separate the secondary view controller.  That's why the views are not popping correctly.  As I mentioned in my answer, it works in the new project because the correct code is there (which Apple includes in new projects).  Comment out your code, and copy their code for those two methods, and you should see that it works.  There's a reason why their code is there. :)

Comment: What got me stumbled is that the working project doesn't implement: -splitViewController:separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:

Comment: Here is an example where it is used.  Your app is running on the iPhone 6 Plus.  In portrait mode, the secondary view controller is collapsed onto the primary view controller, but in landscape mode, the secondary view controller is separate from the primary view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79447/discussion-between-petahchristian-and-loc-pham).

Comment: How can the secondary navigation controller be prevented from pushing on top of the primary navigation controller? The UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods only handle collapse logic for secondary view controller DIRECTLY linked to the UISplitViewController.  In my case, the secondary view controller (namely Detail VC1) is a "Show Detail (e.g. Replace)" segue from the master view controller and the UISplitViewDelegate methods doesn't during this transition.